# Программа не содержит статического метода Main

Tags: c#, visual-studio

В решении есть несколько проектов. Только в одном проекте у меня есть класс Program с методом Main. Всегда все было нормально, а теперь выдает такую ошибку. Не могу понять, в чем проблема. Вроде бы все правильно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Жмем правой кнопкой мыши на проекте вашей лабы —  выбираем set as startup project

Comment: @tym32167 Пробовал, не помогло.

Comment: На скрине ясно видно, что не пробовали

Comment: у Вас даже на скрине видно проект по умолчанию, называется он Menu

Comment: @tym32167  попробовал,все равно не помогло. Создал новое решение, все то же самое. Заметил, что эта ошибка возникает как только я добавляю ссылки в главном проекте на другие проекты.

Comment: покажите скрин, где вы сделали, что я сказал и не помогло

Answer (score 2):

Видно же, что ошибка в проекте Entity.

Точка входа всегда требуется для "Консольного приложения" и "Приложения Windows". Если у вас Entity задумывается, как одно из этих двух вариантов, то добавьте в него соответствующий статический метод, без него никак. Потому что любое приложение должно начинаться с какой-либо точки входа.

Но если вы задумываете этот проект, как "Библиотека классов", то зайдите в свойства проекта и выберите "Выходные данные" - "Библиотека классов". В таком случае точка входа не требуется.